# House Plant identification

Tags: identification

I'll confess to being fairly clueless about plants, and have been trying to find what type this is (present from son to wife for mother's day, with no label or anything to say what it is). Is it better suited to indoors in the pot, or outdoors in the garden (UK location)?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brian, It's a Primula. Here is a link to the Wikipedia entry that should explain all.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primula

Comment: Welcome to Gardening.SE. Could you please add some of the information in your answer instead of just linking external information. At least with some words you should answer the question of OP.

Answer (score 5):

This is a primrose. I work at a greenhouse and we got a few of these in this past year. I can tell you that they are most commonly kept as indoor plants, though they can be planted outside and do well in shady areas with proper water drainage.

They don't like to get a lot of sun, so try not to let it get a lot of direct sunlight. Also, make sure that it stays fairly dry and be especially careful to keep water off the blooms when watering or they will rot.